# Include specific, but variable level of a factor in facetted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have a dataframe with control and treatment groups where specific treatments are associated with specific controls over time. I want to plot each treatment group against its associated control in a faceted manner, but I cannot figure out how to add specific data to the different facets in a frame. I think that I need to create a new column to code a new variable that I will facet across, but I can't figure out how to duplicate the control data when multiple treatments use the same control.

In the following example data frame, the Code column gives the information about which Control is associated with which Treatment. In some cases, a control is associated with only one treatment. In others, the same control is associated with multiple treatments.

```
   Group<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G", "A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
   Group.Type<-c("Con","Con","Con","Trt","Trt","Trt","Trt", "Con","Con","Con","Trt","Trt","Trt","Trt")
   Code <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "A", "A", "B", "C", "NA", "NA", "NA", "A", "A", "B", "C")
   Time <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
   Value<-c(1, 2, 3, 4,2, 1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 3,3, 4)

   data<-data.frame(cbind(Group, Group.Type, Code, Value, Time))
   data$Value <- (as.numeric(data$Value))
```

Basically, I want a faceted plot of a similar format to this one, but I want the values for panel A plotted on panels D and E, and the values for panel B plotted on panel F and the values for panel C plotted on panel G.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(data, aes(x =Time, y = Value)) +geom_point() +geom_line(group = 1)+facet_wrap (~Group)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You create a data to map your controls:

```
map2ctrl = unique(data[data$Code!="NA",c("Group","Code")])

  Group Code
4     D    A
5     E    A
6     F    B
7     G    C
```

The tricky part is that you need to have A, twice (once for D and once for E):

```
newdf = lapply(1:nrow(map2ctrl),function(i){
cbind(data[data$Group %in% sapply(map2ctrl[i,],as.character),],
facet=map2ctrl[i,1])
})
newdf = do.call(rbind,newdf)
```

Then plot (a bit ugly but you have to force Time to numeric, but it works because Time is a factor to begin with):

```
ggplot(newdf) +
geom_point(aes(x =Time, y = Value,col=Group.Type)) +
geom_line(aes(x =as.numeric(Time), y = Value,col=Group.Type))+
facet_wrap (~facet)
```

[image]